# What does V8's ignition really do?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

On https://v8.dev/docs/ignition we can see that:

> Ignition is a fast low-level register-based interpreter written using the backend of TurboFan

on https://docs.google.com/document/d/11T2CRex9hXxoJwbYqVQ32yIPMh0uouUZLdyrtmMoL44/edit?ts=56f27d9d#

> The aim of the Ignition project is to build an interpreter for V8 which executes a low-level bytecode, thus enabling run-once or non-hot code to be stored more compactly in bytecode form.
>
> The interpreter itself consists of a set of bytecode handler code snippets, each of which handles a specific bytecode and dispatches to the handler for the next bytecode. These bytecode handlers
>
> To compile a function to bytecode, the JavaScript code is parsed to generate its AST (Abstract Syntax Tree).  The BytecodeGenerator walks this AST and generates bytecode for each of the AST nodes as appropriate.
>
> Once the graph for a bytecode handler is produced it is passed through a simplified version of  Turbofan’s pipeline and assigned to the corresponding entry in the interpreter table.

So it seems that Ignition job is to take bytecode generated by *BytecodeGenerator* convert it to  bytecode handlers and execute it through `Turbofan`.

But here:
[image]

and here:
[image]

You can see that it is ignition that produces bytecode.

What is more, in this video https://youtu.be/p-iiEDtpy6I?t=722 Ignition is said to be a baseline compiler.

So what's it?
A baseline compiler? A bytecode interpreter? An AST to bytecode transformer?

This image seems to be most appropriate:
[image]

where ignition is just an interpreter and everything before is *no-name bytecode generator/optimizer thing.*

[image]

Comment: Sadly, some of the docs are out of date, including the one with your first graphic above. Full-codegen and Crankshaft are [no longer used at all](https://v8.dev/blog/launching-ignition-and-turbofan), it's purely Ignition+TurboFan.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've changed the image to something more current

Comment: Good stuff. Where did you find those?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder from here: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1OqjVqRhtwlKeKfvMdX6HaCIu9wpZsrzqpIVIwQSuiXQ/ Actually the slides are quite old since they are for this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5OWCtuKiAk given in 2016 but some of them are still relevant

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it's unfortunate that the official docs link to out-of-date information, but hey, they have a LOT to do (and I appreciate their doing it). I'd be tempted to help with the docs but it's a bigger project than I can take on at the mo. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

V8 developer here.

> On https://v8.dev/docs/ignition we can see that:
>
> > Ignition is a fast low-level register-based interpreter written using the backend of TurboFan

Yes, that sums it up. To add a little more detail:

- The name "Ignition" refers to both the Bytecode Generator and the Bytecode Interpreter. Often, the entire thing is also seen as one big black box and casually called "the interpreter", which can sometimes lead to a bit of confusion around the terms.
- The Bytecode Generator takes the AST produced by the Parser for a given JavaScript function, and generates bytecode from it.
- The Bytecode Interpreter takes the bytecode generated by the Bytecode Generator and executes it by interpreting it by sending it to a set of Bytecode Handlers.
- The Bytecode Handlers that make up the Bytecode Interpreter are generated using parts of the Turbofan pipeline. This happens at V8 compilation time, not at runtime. In other words, you need Turbofan to *build* (parts of) Ignition, but not to *run* Ignition.
- The Parser (and the AST/Abstract Syntax Tree it produces are not part of Ignition.

> > Once the graph for a bytecode handler is produced it is passed through a simplified version of Turbofan’s pipeline and assigned to the corresponding entry in the interpreter table.
>
> So it seems that Ignition job is to take bytecode generated by BytecodeGenerator convert it to bytecode handlers and execute it through Turbofan

This section of the design document talks about generating the Bytecode Handlers, which happens "ahead of time" (i.e. when V8 is compiled) using parts of Turbofan. At runtime, bytecode is not *converted* to handlers, it is "handled" (=run, executed, interpreted) by the existing fixed set of handlers, and Turbofan is not involved.

> What is more, in this video https://youtu.be/p-iiEDtpy6I?t=722 Ignition is said to be a baseline compiler.

At that moment, the talk is referring to the general idea that all modern JavaScript engines have a "baseline compiler" (in a very general, conceptual sense -- I agree that the slide could have made that clearer). Note that the slide does not say anything about Ignition. The *next* slide says that Ignition fills that role in V8. So more accurate would be to say "Ignition *takes the place of* a baseline compiler" or "Ignition is a baseline *execution engine*". Or you could redefine your terms slightly and say "Ignition is a compiler that produces bytecode and then interprets it".

> ignition is just an interpreter and everything before is no-name bytecode generator/optimizer thing

That slide shows the "Interpreter" box as part of the "Ignition Bytecode Pipeline". The Bytecode Generator/Optimizer are also part of Ignition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My main point of confusion is that some slides shows that bytecode comes from ignition interpreter and others that bytecode is an input to Ignition. Is "Ignition Bytecode Pipeline" internal part of ignition or is it external, auxiliary part?

Comment: "Pipeline" in this case just means "description of how things happen, in sequence". The parser generates an AST, the bytecode generator generates bytecode from that AST, the bytecode is then first executed a couple of times by the bytecode interpreter and then used as an input to Turbofan for generating optimized code. The term "Ignition" refers to both bytecode generator and bytecode interpreter. (That said, ultimately "Ignition" is just a project name, and for understanding how things work it doesn't really matter which parts of V8's code are covered under that umbrella and which aren't.)

Comment: Ah I think I got it now: Ignition was first an internal project name and then a "catchy umbrella term" for marketing purposes to produce some hype. From technical point of view is not much more than a set of big modifications to V8 shipped circa 2016. There's no "Ignition interpreter", there's just interpreter, generator, compiler, etc. Thanks.

Comment: That's one way to look at it. I'd say there's an Ignition Bytecode Generator and an Ignition Bytecode Interpreter, so "Ignition" is both of those together. But yeah, what matters is the code and what it does, not so much the names you use to refer to various parts.

Comment: well, some people in your team seem not to notice the existence of a generator and give all the credit to interpreter, i.e. you can read things like "bytecode produced by V8's Ignition interpreter" on your team blog here: https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-56

Comment: As I wrote originally: "Often, the entire thing is also seen as one big black box and casually called "the interpreter", which can sometimes lead to a bit of confusion around the terms." In that specific quote, I would guess the intention was to be more specific than just saying "produced by Ignition" by including a one-word summary of what "Ignition" is. Rest assured that people are well aware that bytecode must be generated somehow ;-)

Comment: @jmrk, is it true that ignition executes bytecode and interprets it into machine code in order for browser to understand. And as our application is being executed by ignition, the profiler analyzes and seeks for hot functions and if it finds then it passes hot functions to compiler to optimize.Then after optimizations done by compiler, the compiler changes parts of the machine code(interpreted by ignition) with optimized code. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, mostly. (1st sentence:) Interpreting bytecode does not involve creating machine code -- that's why we call it "interpreting" and not "compiling". (Last sentence:) When optimized machine code for a function is available, the function's bytecode is replaced by that optimized machine code. (Strictly speaking both will be kept around, but the point is that the next invocation will use the machine code, not the byte code.)

Comment: @jmrk, does browser understand bytecode?, that is, when ignition interprets bytecode then what will be the output?

Comment: Ignition understands bytecode and executes it; that's what "interpreting" means. There is no output, just whatever the respective function does and/or returns. (You can think of it as "Ignition executes bytecode just like a CPU executes machine code".)

Answer (score 6):

<s>As I mentioned in a comment, sadly some of the docs are out of date, including the one with your first graphic above. Full-codegen and Crankshaft are [no longer used at all](https://v8.dev/blog/launching-ignition-and-turbofan), it's purely parsing and Ignition + TurboFan.</s> *(you've removed the image from the outdated docs that sadly are still linked by some of the V8 docs)*

Ignition is a high-speed bytecode interpreter.

V8's parser produces Ignition bytecode. That bytecode is executed (interpreted) by Ignition. Code that only runs once (startup code and such) or isn't run often stays at the bytecode level and continues to be executed by Ignition.

"Hot" code goes to the second phase, where TurboFan kicks in: TurboFan's input is the same bytecode that Ignition interprets (rather than source code, as it was with Crankshaft), which it then aggressively compiles to highly-optimized machine code that runs directly (rather than being interpreted).

[This article](https://v8.dev/blog/launching-ignition-and-turbofan) goes into the motivations for moving off Full-codegen and Crankshaft (memory savings in the former case, difficulty implementing and in particular optimizing language features in the second). The design of TurboFan also helps the V8 authors minimize the amount of platform-specific code they have to write (by having an intermediate representation, which amongst other things they can also use to write Ignition's bytecode handlers).

Comment: good day Mr.Crowder thank you for such a great answer and I would kindly like to ask some questions))). Mr.Crowder, ok, parser generates AST and then bytecode. Then, generated bytecode is executed by Ignition and on runtime Profiler monitors and seeks for optimizations to be done and if the Profiler finds hot functions then TurboFan optimizes them. So, TurboFan optimizes code on the fly. Mr.Crowder, the question I want to ask is why Ignition was introduced in V8, I think thanks to ignition we have more compact and efficient machine code generated from bytecode. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, Mr.Crowder, is it really true that parser generates bytecode and not Ignition. In majority of articles it is written that bytecode is generated by Ignition itself but you wrote above that parser generates bytecode.

Comment: @Dickens - *"I think thanks to ignition we have more compact and efficient machine code generated from bytecode."* I don't think so, no. The original motivation for Ignition was to reduce memory consumption on mobiles, see [the linked article](https://v8.dev/blog/launching-ignition-and-turbofan) for details. *"is it really true that parser generates bytecode and not Ignition"* The parser is *part of* Ignition.

Comment: is it true that ignition executes bytecode and interprets it into machine code in order for browser to understand. And as our application is being executed by ignition, the profiler analyzes and seeks for hot functions and if it finds then it passes hot functions to compiler to optimize.Then after optimizations fone by compiler, the compiler changes parts of the code with optimized code. Is that correct? sir

Comment: @Dickens - Essentially, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Please correct my mistake in understanding the conversion process:

- JS code parsed into AST
- AST sent to Ignition to be converted into bytecode
- Generate Machine Code
- If byte code is optimal, Send it to the CPU for processing
- If byte code needs optimization, it is sent to Turbofan for optimization
- If Turbofan received byte code, it further optimizes, and sent to computer for processing.

Comment: If you have a question, please ask a new question rather than asking it in the answers of another question. What you describe is not how V8 works. V8 has no concept of "optimal" bytecode. Ignition doesn't generate machine code.